# How to catch unhandled exceptions in the Room persistence library

Tags: java, android, android-room

**Background:**

I am using the Room persistence library in my Android (Java) project to support local caching of data. Room operates on dedicated threads when querying or saving data.

**Problem:**

If an exception is thrown in one of these threads managed by Room, then the whole application crashes. This can happen in case of data inconsistencies such as data not matching the current schema. This is highly problematic. I would rather prefer to handle such exceptions on my own and wipe all data in the local database - this is better than leaving a user with a completely broken and irrepairable app.

Example exception:

```
2020-01-22 12:45:08.252 9159-11043/com.xyz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_1
    Process: com.xyz, PID: 9159
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "primary" (class com.xyz.model.remotedatasource.sampleApi.entities.ProfileImage), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "isPrimary", "url"])
        at [Source: (byte[])":)
    ... -1, column: 402] (through reference chain: com.xyz.model.remotedatasource.sampleApi.entities.Candidate["profileImages"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.xyz.model.remotedatasource.sampleApi.entities.ProfileImage["primary"])
        at com.xyz.model.localdatasource.Converters.deserialize(Converters.java:113)
        at com.xyz.model.localdatasource.Converters.toCandidate(Converters.java:73)
        at com.xyz.model.localdatasource.LocalDao_Impl$4.call(LocalDao_Impl.java:270)
        at com.xyz.model.localdatasource.LocalDao_Impl$4.call(LocalDao_Impl.java:217)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
            ... 3 more
```

Example data access object (DAO):

```
public interface LocalDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Match")
    LiveData<List<Match>> getMatches();

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void saveMatches(List<Match> matches);
}
```

**Question**

Since Room performs many operations in background threads I would expect a way to register a custom error handler. Do you know how to achieve this? If not, do you have any other suggestions on how to wipe the database automatically if such exceptions occur?

Comment: I recommend that you provide a [mcve] showing your DAO. Or, at minimum: what are your DAO methods returning? My guess is that they are returning `LiveData`.

Comment: Yes, they are returning LiveData. I added the DAO definition.

Comment: `LiveData` cannot raise errors. That is one of the reasons why I am not a fan of having a DAO use `LiveData`. If you switch to an RxJava type (e.g., `Single`, `Observable`), you should get errors through the normal RxJava chain. Or, if someday you move to Kotlin, your exception should get exposed through normal `suspend` and `Flow` processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal can be achieved by registering a custom thread executing having a custom exception handler.

I came up with the following solution:

```
public abstract class LocalDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String TAG = LocalDatabase.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final Object syncObj = new Object();
    private static LocalDatabase localDatabase;
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> dbToInstanceId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> threadToInstanceId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public abstract LocalDao getDao();

    public static LocalDatabase getInstance() {
        if (localDatabase == null) {
            localDatabase = buildDb();
        }
        return localDatabase;
    }

    private static LocalDatabase buildDb() {
        // keep track of which thread belongs to which local database
        final String instanceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // custom thread with an exception handler strategy
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            ThreadFactory defaultThreadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
            Thread thread = defaultThreadFactory.newThread(runnable);
            thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(resetDatabaseOnUnhandledException);
            threadToInstanceId.put(thread.getId(), instanceId);
            return thread;
        });

        LocalDatabase localDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
                LocalDatabase.class, "LocalDatabase")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .setQueryExecutor(executor)
                .build();
        dbToInstanceId.put(localDatabase.hashCode(), instanceId);
        return localDatabase;
    }

    static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler resetDatabaseOnUnhandledException = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("", "uncaught exception in a LocalDatabase thread, resetting the database", throwable);
            synchronized (syncObj) {
                // there is no active local database to clean up
                if (localDatabase == null) return;

                String instanceIdOfThread = threadToInstanceId.get(thread.getId());
                String instanceIdOfActiveLocalDb = dbToInstanceId.get(localDatabase.hashCode());
                if(instanceIdOfThread == null || !instanceIdOfThread.equals(instanceIdOfActiveLocalDb)) {
                    // the active local database instance is not the one that caused this thread to fail, so leave it as is
                    return;
                }

                localDatabase.tryResetDatabase();
            }
        }
    };

    public void tryResetDatabase() {
        try {
            String dbName = this.getOpenHelper().getDatabaseName();

            // try closing existing connections
            try {
                if(this.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().isOpen()) {
                    this.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().close();
                }
                if(this.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase().isOpen()) {
                    this.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase().close();
                }
                if (this.isOpen()) {
                    this.close();
                }
                if(this == localDatabase) localDatabase = null;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close LocalDatabase", ex);
            }

            // try deleting database file
            File f = App.getContext().getDatabasePath(dbName);
            if (f.exists()) {
                boolean deleteSucceeded = SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(f);
                if (!deleteSucceeded) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not delete LocalDatabase");
                }
            }

            LocalDatabase tmp = buildDb();
            tmp.query("SELECT * from Match", null);
            tmp.close();

            this.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase();
            this.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
            this.query("SELECT * from Match", null);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("", "Could not reset LocalDatabase", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found "executor " never run?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is something you can do about these, it assumes schemas is correct but if something is wrong with the data or schema then you can handle the things like this when inserting or doing any operation over them.

Just mark the DAO functions as throwable methods and handle the possible error at caller side.

```
public interface LocalDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Match")
    LiveData<List<Match>> getMatches() throws Exception;

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void saveMatches(List<Match> matches) throws Exception;

    @Query("DELETE FROM Match")
    public void nukeTable();
}
```

now at caller side just call this handling the exception.

```
public getMatches(){
  //... some code
  try{
    //some code goes here
   dao.getMatches();
  }catch(Exception exp){
    //if something happens bad then nuke the table on background thread
   dao.nukeTable()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately the exceptions are still thrown in a separate thread.

Comment: check this if it helps

https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/697e543652b03d3d2a06703f5d6b44b5#file-datadatabase-kt