# Clear (reset) all Room database if there is a conflict

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to clear automatically all the Room database if there is a conflict (bad key, column,...) ?

Comment: won't a conflict just be some sort of exception ? you could then handle that exception as you'd see fit, right ?

Comment: check if helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782724/6478047

Comment: @jéwôm I think it would be helpful to explain your particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use - [Fallback Destructive Migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#handle-missing-migrations)